# JSONError - System.JSONException: Can not start an object, expecting field name

Tags: apex, json, jsongenerator

I would like to create JSON as a output, for that I have written one sample code, but in that code on line no 30 I am getting error as, 'System.JSONException: Can not start an object, expecting field name' can anyone please provide me the way to minimize that error

```
    public class JSonGeneratorDemo {

    public class Employee{
        String val = '';
        public Employee(){
           // this.val = val;
        }
    }    
    public static void generateJSONContent(){

        JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
        List<Integer> intList = new List<Integer>();
            intList.add(101);
            intList.add(201);
            intList.add(301);

        Employee test = new Employee();

        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField('Orgnization', 'Prorigo Software Pvt. Ltd.');
        gen.writeStringField('EmpName', 'Amol Jadhav');
        gen.writeNumberField('EmpId', 10);
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeObjectField('Remaining Employee Ids', intList);
        gen.writeEndObject();
        gen.writeFieldName('Demo Field');
        gen.writeObject(test);
        gen.writeEndObject();

        String pretty = gen.getAsString(); // Error on this line
        //System.debug('The Generated JSON :' +pretty);


    }
}
```

Comment: Much easier to serialize a class if you can. Should be few use cases where you need to use a generator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to specify name of field before creating object as value.
if you want to have an array as value for `Remaining Employee Ids` field, you don't need to create object for it.

```
    gen.writeStartObject();
    gen.writeStringField('Orgnization', 'Prorigo Software Pvt. Ltd.');
    gen.writeStringField('EmpName', 'Amol Jadhav');
    gen.writeNumberField('EmpId', 10);
    gen.writeFieldName('Remaining Employee Ids');
    gen.writeObject(intList);
    gen.writeFieldName('Demo Field');
    gen.writeObject(test);
    gen.writeEndObject();
```

results in

```
{
    "Orgnization" : "Prorigo Software Pvt. Ltd.",
    "EmpName" : "Amol Jadhav",
    "EmpId" : 10,
    "Remaining Employee Ids" : [ 101, 201, 301 ],
    "Demo Field" : {
        "attributes" : {
            "type" : "Employee"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Alexander it has worked for me. thanks again for your time and help

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi Unless I am missing something, you are using character constants for your strings. I am surprised that that would compile. Maybe consider replacing `'` with `"` for your JsonGenerator fields. Good Jackson tip though! Appreciated.